# Sublime Text 2 in Lubuntu shows default icon from system

Tags: lubuntu, icons, sublime-text, installed-programs, lxpanel

I installed Sublime Text 2 by PPA in Lubuntu 16.10 and all works fine. The only problem is that Sublime Text show a default icon in the panel's window list:

[image: Screenshot]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Could you try another icon theme? According to https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=184421, the gnome icon theme may have an icon for sublime text. On my system, Lubuntu 16.04, there doesn't seem to be any icon for sublime-text. `find -iname "*sublime*" -type f` comes up empty.

Comment: @eliah-kagan nice to see you again :)